# What is the purpose of Promise.resolve(null)

Tags: typescript, firebase, promise, firebase-authentication

I'm looking at firebase sdk and there is a line where the getAuth token method returns a Promise that resolves to null? I've seen this pattern a few times and am confused what the purpose of this is.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/ee610626bef1f6f05852041b2161c01c5e99aa59/packages/app/src/firebaseApp.ts#L67

Comment: To resolve a promise while the resolved value is unimportant.

Comment: Probably just to return a `Promise` whose value is `null`

Comment: maybe they do not want to leave it in blank and they used a default value that is null

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a "pattern" per se, at least where you're looking at it right now.  It seems to me, after digging around in the code, that what you're seeing here is just the given behavior of `getToken()` for the object where it's defined.  Note that `INTERNAL` is of type [FirebaseAppInternals](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/0acd32c07703a6976a21350e00d02bab9d74e7ac/packages/app-types/private.d.ts#L68), which says that `getToken()` can return either null or a FirebaseAuthTokenData.  This implementation is simply returning null all the time.  It's just canned behavior - this object is simply never going to yield a token when invoked (there is no user logged in).  Other implementations might actually return a token if the circumstances are right.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But thought it worth mentioning. `Promise.resolve(null)` immediately resolves the promise, but the delegate you pass to `.then(()=> {})` on the returned Promise will be placed on the microtask queue. Similar to `window.setTimeout(()=> {}, 0);` (not exactly the same, but very similar).

I've seen this documented on MDN, but I cannot find the page now. If anyone does find that page feel free to edit my answer.